# Why does gin SetCookie add new cookies but not change the old ones?

Tags: go

I'm trying to test the Logout handler where there is a `ctx.SetCookie` method:

```
func (a *authController) Logout(ctx *gin.Context) {
    refreshToken, err := ctx.Cookie("refresh_token")
    ...
    ctx.SetCookie("access_token", "", -1, "/", "localhost", false, true)
    ctx.SetCookie("refresh_token", "", -1, "/", "localhost", false, true)
    ctx.SetCookie("logged_in", "", -1, "/", "localhost", false, true)

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "success"})

}
```

code inside the test function:

```
recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
ctx, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(recorder)
ctx.SetCookie("logged_in", "truee", 60*60, "/", "localhost", false, false)
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/logout", nil)
http.SetCookie(recorder, &http.Cookie{Name: "refresh_token", Value: "encodedRefreshToken", MaxAge: 60 * 60, Path: "/", Domain: "localhost", Secure: false, HttpOnly: true}})
http.SetCookie(recorder, &http.Cookie{Name: "access_token", Value: "encodedAccessToken", MaxAge: 60 * 60, Path: "/", Domain: "localhost", Secure: false, HttpOnly: true})
req.Header = http.Header{"Cookie": recorder.Result().Header["Set-Cookie"]}
ctx.Request = req
test.mock()
authController.Logout(ctx)
```

After the call, I'm trying to check if the cookies have been deleted:

```
coockies := recorder.Result().Cookies()
for _, c := range coockies {
    if c.Name == "access_token" {
        assert.Equal(t, "", c.Value)
    }
    ...
}
```

And I face such a problem that setCookie does not change cookies , but adds new ones . That is, after calling this method, I have two pairs of cookies with access Token, etc.

And as a result, the tests do not pass. I don't understand I'm doing something wrong and can it be solved somehow? or is that how it should be ?

Comment: Your test code has no user agent that keeps, updates or deletes cookies. Your test of cookie deletion is just deeply flawed. That's just not how cookies work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `AddCookie` to set cookie for the `recorder`.**

I think you should test the `Logout` handler like this:

```golang
package ${your_package}

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func Logout(ctx *gin.Context) {
    // refreshToken, err := ctx.Cookie("refresh_token")
    ctx.SetCookie("access_token", "", -1, "/", "localhost", false, true)
    ctx.SetCookie("refresh_token", "", -1, "/", "localhost", false, true)
    ctx.SetCookie("logged_in", "", -1, "/", "localhost", false, true)

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "success"})
}

func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/logout", Logout)
    return r
}

func TestLogout(t *testing.T) {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r := setupRouter()
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/logout", nil)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{Name: "refresh_token", Value: "encodedRefreshToken", MaxAge: 60 * 60, Path: "/", Domain: "localhost", Secure: false, HttpOnly: true})
    req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{Name: "access_token", Value: "encodedAccessToken", MaxAge: 60 * 60, Path: "/", Domain: "localhost", Secure: false, HttpOnly: true})
    r.ServeHTTP(w, req)

    for _, v := range w.Result().Cookies() {
        if v.Name == "access_token" {
            assert.Equal(t, "", v.Value)
        }
    }
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, w.Code)
    respBody := &gin.H{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(w.Body.Bytes(), respBody)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, gin.H{"status": "success"}, *respBody)
}
```

```
=== RUN   TestLogout
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.

[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
 - using env:   export GIN_MODE=release
 - using code:  gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

[GIN-debug] GET    /logout                   --> app.Logout (3 handlers)
[GIN] 2022/09/19 - 10:46:00 | 200 |          81µs |                 | GET      "/logout"
--- PASS: TestLogout (0.00s)
PASS
```

Reference: https://gin-gonic.com/docs/testing/